# Rails 4, strong_parameters, dynamic attr_accessible: how to get parent db info into class instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, attr-accessible, strong-parameters

I'm trying to add `attr_accessible` to a User model based on its parent Account. I know the the user class instance doesn't yet have access to its parent, but I can't figure out how to do this. Any suggestions would be awesome.

This is how I'm getting `strong_params` to work, and would like to do similar in User Model (or do something better).

```
#appilcation_controller
  ...
  def config_permitted_parameters
   ...
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(*user_attributes)}
  end

  def user_attributes
    attrs = [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :primary_account, :account_id]
    @account.user_attributes.each do |att|
      attrs << att[0].to_sym
    end
    attrs
  end
```

This is what works now:

```
#User.rb

%w[no_call_list informal_name].each do |key|
  attr_accessible key
  store_accessor :properties, key
  scope "has_#{key}", lambda { |value| where("properties @> hstore(?, ?)", key, value) }
end
```

This is what I would *like* to work:

```
#User.rb

#@account.user_attributes.each do |key|
#current_user.account.user_attributes.each do |key|
  attr_accessible key
  store_accessor :properties, key
  scope "has_#{key}", lambda { |value| where("properties @> hstore(?, ?)", key, value) }
end
```